# Having trouble with jQuery .click()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure why the jquery .click is not triggering, please help.
HTML/js can be found here `enter code here`https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/10192/

.click() does not work even when if statements are removed, I am aware that left does not work on start due to position = 1.

Comment: post your complete code.

Comment: can you post your full jQuery and html code. what you trying to achieve through click? Also did you added jQuery library before your script code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Two things need to be correct:-***

***1.*** this code:-

```
$('div.left-arrow').click(function() { 
    if (position > 1){
        //your code here
    }
});
```

It will never go forward because `if` condition will return false (as you already defined `position =1`).

*So either change this condition to `position >= 1` or make `position =2; //or more`*

***2.*** Your both `left-arrow` and `right-arrow` div's have no content. so physically they don't occupy any area on browser, and clicking to them is not possible.

*So Add some `icon/content`  or add some `CSS height/width` so that physically click will be possible.*

***Solution for your problem:-***

Add `z-index: 99;`  like below:-

```
.left-arrow{
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index: 99;
}
.right-arrow{
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

***And don't forget to change condition `position >1` to `position >= 1`***

Working example:- https://jsfiddle.net/4ywa7a5x/

Comment: added CSS to jsfiddle

Comment: @BrandonWheeler  i have given solution in my edited answer.Please check

Comment: @BrandonWheeler   did you checked the edited answer?

Answer (score 0):

I found your code have this line.

```
var position = 1;
```

And inside your click function

```
$('div.left-arrow').click(function() { 
    if (position > 1){
        //your code here
    }
});
```

This will never work because your `position` is 1. So made it `2` for work or

```
$('div.left-arrow').click(function() { 
    if (position >= 1){
        //your code here
    }
});
```

However, I click into both of your `div` section with your code `position -= 1;` it still works file

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery.click is triggering in right way. You have applied condition that if "position> 1" only then it will trigger and you have initialized "position =1" that is why it is not triggering, once you set "position> 1" it will trigger.

Answer (score 0):

define function as below and give the proper css to div by that it ll acquire proper space in browser.

```
$('.left-arrow').click(function() { });
```